# Number of tangent lines to an algebraic curve passing through a given point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $C=V(f)\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a smooth plane algebraic curve of degree $d$.
>
> 1. For all $x\in \mathbb{P}^2\setminus C$ there are at most $d(d-1)$ tangent lines to $C$ passing through $x$.
> 2. There exists an $x$ such that we have an equality in the statement above.

For the first part I have tried to do this: After a translation we can assume that $x=(0:0:1)$, then as an arbitrary line passing through $x$ has exactly one intersection with the line at infinity we have an unique parametric representation in the form $l_{(a:b)}=\{(a\mu:b\mu:\lambda); \lambda,\mu \in k\}$ for some $(a:b)\in \mathbb{P}^1$.

Now, $l_{(a:b)}$ is tangent to $C$ $\iff$ one of the equations  $f(ax,bx,1)=0$ or $f(a,b,x)=0$ has a multiple root $\iff$ one of the associated discriminants $\Delta_{(a:b)}$ or $\hat{\Delta}_{(a:b)}$ vanished.

If $(a:b)\neq (1:0)$ we can take $b=1$ and studying $P(a)=\Delta_{(a:1)}$ and $Q(a)=\hat{\Delta}_{(a:1)}$ as polynomials in $a$ so it would be enough to prove the following

> $\deg(P)+\deg(Q)+\#(\{\Delta_{(1:0)}\}\cap \{0\})+\#(\{\hat{\Delta}_{(1:0)}\}\cap \{0\})\leq d(d-1)$

But I don't know how to compute $\deg(P)$ or $\deg(Q)$ so I don't know hot to continue.

For the second part perhaps I could take $x=(c:0:1)$ and make computations similar to those above to obtain expressions of the form $\Delta_{c,(a:b)}$ and $\hat{\Delta}_{c,(a:b)}$. Then if we define $P^c(a)=\Delta_{c,(a:1)}$ and $Q^c(a)=\hat{\Delta}_{c,(a:1)}$ maybe we can choose $c\in k$ such that $P^c$ and $Q^c$ have different roots and $\Delta_{c,(1:0)},\hat{\Delta}_{c,(1:0)}\neq 0$. Then $\deg(P^c)+\deg(Q^c)$ would be equal to the number of tangent lines, and a good understanding of the first part should give us a way to compute this.

As noticed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45434/proving-that-the-genus-of-a-nonsingular-plane-curve-is-fracd-1d-22) assuming Hurwitz's formula this problem is equivalent to Plücker's Formula and that's where my interest comes from.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve): The degree of the dual is the number of tangents to the X that can be drawn through a given point. The points where these tangents touch the curve are the points of intersection between the curve and the polar curve with respect to the given point. If the degree of the curve is d then the degree of the polar is d − 1 and so the number of tangents that can be drawn through the given point is at most d(d − 1).

Comment: Thanks @Jan-MagnusØkland, it seems that that is the right approach so I'm going to read more about the dual curve. Besides, I like solutions to enumerative problems which end up translating the problem to an intersection of varieties and using Bezout.

Comment: [Fulton, W. (1984). Introduction to intersection theory in algebraic geometry (No. 54). American Mathematical Soc. p.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBuUH.png)

Comment: Thats a nice and simple solution!, you can put it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Fulton, W. (1984). Introduction to intersection theory in algebraic geometry (No. 54). American Mathematical Soc. p.2:

> **1.2 Class of a curve (Plücker).** An important early application of Bézout's theorem was for the calculation of the *class* of a plane curve $C$., i.e., the number of tangents to $C$ through a given general point $Q$: [image: The class of a curve] Equivalently, the class of $C$ is the degree of the dual curve $C^{\vee}$. If $F(x,y,z)$ is the homogeneous polynomial defining $C$ and $Q=(a:b:c)$, then the *polar curve* $C_Q$ is defined by $$F_Q(x,y,z)=aF_x+bF_y+cF_z,$$ where $F_x=\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial x},F_y,F_z$ are partial derivatives. This is defined so that a nonsingular point $P$ of $C$ is on $C_Q$ exactly when the tangent line to $C$ at $P$ (defined by $xF_x(P)+yF_y(P)+zF_z(P)=0$) passes through $Q$. One checks that $C$ meets $C_Q$ transversally at $P$ if $P$ is not a flex on $C$, so $$\operatorname{class}(C)=\#C\cap C_Q = \deg{C}\deg{C_Q}=n(n-1),$$ if $n$ is the degree of $C$, and $C$ is nonsingular.
>
> If $C$ has singular points, however, they are always on $C\cap C_Q$, so they must contribute. For example, if $P$ is an ordinary node (resp. cusp) and $Q$ is general, then $$i(P,C\cdot C_Q)=2 (\text{resp. } i(P,C\cdot C_Q))=3).$$ This gives the first Plücker formula [50] $$n(n-1)=\operatorname{class}(C)+2\delta+3\kappa,$$ if $C$ has degree $n$, $\delta$ ordinary nodes, $\kappa$ ordinary cusps, and no other singularities.
>
> [50] Plücker, J. *Solution d'une question fondamentale concernant la théorie générale des courbes.*. Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik, 1834(12), pp. 105-108. doi:10.1515/crll.1834.12.105