# Genus of a curve is $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading the arithmetic of elliptic curves by Silverman and I found problems with the following exercise:

Let $F(x,y,z)$ an homogeneus polynomial of degree $d$. Let $C$ be a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by the equation $F=0$ which is non singular. Prove that its genus is $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$

The idea of the exercise is to define a map $\phi:C\to\mathbb{P}^1$, for example $\phi([x:y:z])=[x:y]$ and then use Hurwit's formula. This gives us:
$$2g(C)-2=-2\deg(\phi)+\sum_{P\in C}(e_\phi(P)-1)$$
And from here I have two things to prove:

- $\deg(\phi)=d$
- $\sum_{P\in C}(e_\phi(P)-1)=d(d-1)$

I've seen this post [Proving that the genus of a nonsingular plane curve is $\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45434/proving-that-the-genus-of-a-nonsingular-plane-curve-is-fracd-1d-22), but this is very geometric, and I've seen books that proves this with Pluker's formula, but this looks very sophisiticated. Since I am studying a particular book, I would like to have a solution just involving results of the book, how can I prove those two things usind the definitions given in the book?

Many thanks.

Edit: Here is my attempt:

WLOG we can assume $[0:0:1]\notin C$ (if $[0:0:1]\in C$ we can take a change of coordinates) and define $\phi([x:y:z])=[x:y]$. Notice that $\forall~[x_0:y_0]\in\mathbb{P}^1$ we have:
$$\phi^{-1}([x_0,y_0])=\lbrace [x_0:y_0:z]\mid F(x_0,y_0,z)=0\rbrace$$
So $p(z)=F(x_0,y_0,z)$ is a polynomial in $z$ of degree $d$. Since we are in an algebraic closed field $p(z)$ has $d$ roots (not necessarily different) and so $\deg(\phi)=d$.

To study the ramification points we need to study the points where $|\phi^{-1}([x_0:y_0])|<d$, that is, the points $[x:y]\in\mathbb{P}^1$ such that the system of equations $F(x,y,z)=0,\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x.y,z)=0$ has solutions. By Bezout's theorem since $\deg(F)=d$ and $\deg\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right)=d-1$ if they do not have common components   (i.e the multiplicity of the roots is at most $2$) they intersect in $d(d-1)$ points. Then there are $d(d-1)$ zeroes of order $2$ and thus there are $d(d-1)$ points with ramification index $2$, which implies $\sum_{P\in C}(e_\phi(P)-1)=d(d-1)$.

It left to study the cases where there are roots of multiplicity $>2$. But this is ok? My issue is that I have not used the fact that $F$ is non singular.

Comment: For those of us who don't have the book in front of us, could you give an idea of what the tools available are? For instance, my favorite proof of this (which may or may not be "allowed" for you) is by using the short exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{I}_X\cong \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^2}(-d)\to \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^2}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to 0$ and then observing that the arithmetic and geoemtric genuses are the same for a smooth curve.

Comment: The hint in the exercise is for you to define a map from $C$ to $\Bbb{P}^1$. It need not be exactly the map had in mind.

Comment: Mind you, if you have zero prior exposure to algebraic geometry, then Silverman's book is advancing at a relatively quick pace in the first two chapters. I think of it as part review, part covering the basics with the weights of the two parts really depending on your background. It is a great book, but it is a tall order to cover all the AG background in 40 pages. The exercise are good, but you undoubtedly saw that he refers to Harsthorne or Shafarevich or Matsumura for many basic results.

Comment: (cont'd) This is not uncommon in AG. Hartshorne does the same. If you want to get to the bottom of things, that's great, but a possible (and possibly more efficient) workflow is to build an inner intuitive picture of the concepts and results and accept a few things from AG on faith. It actually works, and you can always fill in more details later. When I was in or barely out of grad school (my topic was rep theory of algebraic groups), I was told to *believe in algebraic geometry*. At a table discussion with one of the top guys in the area said: *You haven't read all of EGA! Shame on you!*

Comment: (cont'd) His facial expression told the story. He was joking, and had not absorbed all the details himself.

Comment: @KReiser FWIW Up to this point Silverman has covered divisors, Picard group, differentials and their divisors, Riemann-Roch, Hurwitz genus formula invoving ramification degrees but without different exponents. As an inequality, but explaining that it has equality when wild ramification can be excluded. Nothing about sheaves. Basically geared to study curves only, I think.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know that  it skips many proofs and probably it is not the easiest book to get started. I have some background on basic algebraic geometry and I used this book for understanding ramifications and Hurwitz, that is what I was trying to solve this exercise. I understand how to do computations of these kinds in particular examples, the problem is that I don't know how to do it in general, when I don't know nothing about the map nor the curve. Intuitively I can belive that $deg(\phi)=d$, but for a general polynomial I dont have any clue on how to study the ramifications.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen About the map, if I take $C$ to be a curve such that $[0:1:0]\notin C$ (I can do it with a change of coordinates) why I can't take WLOG this map?

Comment: At least the answer by Matt E in the other thread needed a bit more care in the choice of the line. He wanted to exclude the possibility of higher order tangency (IIRC). About the rest: sorry about being so verbose. Earlier I have encountered people with a very shallow background trying to delve into Silverman. I was catering for that. You'll do fine.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Don't worry, there are many people in StackExange that asks for problems that they are not able to solve, so I understand you. I added an attempt (with some details left), maybe you can check it and tell me whether I am right or not.